# How to learn word embedding from a context on the fly?

Tags: word-embeddings, nlp

Consider the fictional word tahiliuk in the sentence “We found a small, fluffy tahiliuk running around our garden.” While hearing a new word used in context, people are remarkably adept at inferring a basic notion of a its meaning.

**Question:** How the tahiliuk's vector could be learned from the context?

**Assumption:** 
a fixed input vocabulary, mapped to a set of word vectors.

**Remarks:**

1. Tahiliuk is a completely new word. There is now such word within
   training data.
2. Using approaches like "fastText" will not work here because of
   tahiliuk is a random word.
3. One possible way is to initialize the embedding  as the sum of their context words and then rapidly refine the embedding with a high learning rate. This approach is used in the following paper, but this approach seems to be not perfect

*Herbelot, A., & Baroni, M. (2017). High-risk learning: acquiring new word vectors from tiny data. In Proceedings of the 2017 Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing.*